# Apache is running but not working

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I am running a huge php-application on an ubuntu server, using apache2, php5, mysql.

Sometimes (approx. once a month) the page ist not reachable from the internet ("it's down").
The weird thing is, that `service apache2 status` says that apache is running.
The solution is always to restart apache using `service apache2 restart` and everything works fine again.

The server load is at a minimum and can't be part of the problem (I guess).

I know, this description is not as detailed as it should be, but I do not have more information.

**Any suggestions about what could cause this problem are appreciated!**

Comment: Since this is not a programming question it's offtopic on Stack Overflow. Might want to try at superuser subsite. Apart from that - check your MPM settings in apache2.conf, and lower the `MaxConnectionsPerChild` if it's ridiculously high. Also regularly giving Apache a `SIGHUP` could solve the problem.

Comment: Not superuser - should be on serverfault

Answer (score 1):

Disable Firewall or Antivirus and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Change `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` => change all `AllowOverride all`,

and make sure that `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000.default.conf` => verify the path of the Directory that you access.

Answer (score 0):

assign the necessary permissions of the webroot directory for the domain.

```
chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).